# Android Consume WebService, Exception HttpTransportSE.call()

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap

Good evening, I'm a long time trying to consume one simpes WS, already researched and tried different ways to solve this error and failed, tried different versions of kSOAP, 2.5.2, 2.6.0, 3.0.0, 3.3,0. ..Gostaria love to know how to solve. Every time I come "transporte.call (SOAP_ACTION sobre);" generates a null exception. 
PS: WS is free, this is the link if they want to access: 
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx

and this is my code:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusT  oFahrenheit";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    try{

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");           

        SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sobre.dotNet = true;
        sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 30000);

        transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, sobre);

        SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive)sobre.getResponse();

        tv.setText("" + resultado.toString());

    }catch(Exception e){
        tv.setText(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Thanks for sharing the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

You got wrong namespace, method and soap action

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT:**

This works:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
//private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
//private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
//private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";
String result = ""; 

TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    try{
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");           

        final SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sobre.dotNet = true;
        sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        final HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 30000);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, sobre);

                    SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive)sobre.getResponse();

                    result = resultado.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        int countWait = 5; 
        while (result.isEmpty() && countWait > 0){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
            countWait--;
        }
        tv.setText(result);

    }catch(Exception e){
        tv.setText(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

The problem was that you could not do network operations in the main thread. Plus some namespace and other constants problems.

Comment: Hello Serge, I changed the "namespace, method, soap action", and not resolved, 
remains the exception in method ".call ()"

Comment: I looked at WSDL and it actually shows `private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";` with slash at the end. Can you try this?

Comment: Can you check if transporte is null ? Can you also add stack to your question?

Comment: Yes the transporta returns null exception, u have email? If u want i can send the project on your email

Answer (score 0):

The code from serge  work , but need something

Dont see thread so , need police for access in the main tread add this

`StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

or use asinctask

```
class DemoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    //Your implementation 
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO: do something with the feed
}
```

}